# Is it safe to format C: drive in order to deploy Linux on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have deployed several distros *on* Windows, such as Open SUSE Enterprise Server 15, Kali, and Ubuntu, but want to turn my currently Windows 10 machine to a Linux machine.

Is Virtual Machine the best way to go, or is it better to possibly format and wipe my machine and start from scratch?

I have deployed the Windows Subsystem, but I want a completely Linux machine.

Comment: What is your definition of safe? If you format C, you will definately loose some data.

Comment: I am wondering if formatting my C: drive will destroy my computer and whether partitioning or something else would be better.  I currently have everything on my C: drive and recovery drive backed up to an external hard drive.

Comment: If you do not care about the data on the disk you can wipe it. The distro's installer will write a new partition table for you. If anything goes wrong you can install Windows again if needed, it will write it's own partition table again.

Comment: formatting the C: drive does not destroy a computer

Comment: While you do not understand that much how a computer works, I would advise staying with WSL to get the hang of it

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance!  Favour returned, question upvoted!  **;-)**

Comment: ...It's not upvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that and Windows will be gone **together with all its applications, data, ...**

*However*, as you're new to Linux (I'm impressed with all the stuff you have running under Windows if you're really a N00b), why not go multi-boot?

So take a [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) system backup on an external HD before you start, shrink the Windows C: drive to the minimum + 15%, install Ubuntu as that's the easiest to install on 3 partitions:

- `/` for the OS
- `/home` for its data
- `swap` equal to SQRT(RAM) if you do not plan on using hibernation in any Linux Distro and RAM+SQRT(RAM) if you do plan on using hibernation.

then install OpenSUSE on 2 extra partitions:

- `/` for the OS
- `/home` for its data
- the existing `swap` partition can be reused by OpenSUSE!

And for heaven's sake: **Keep Kali on a USB stick** and only insert the USB stick to boot Kali when you need it!
*It's a [very specialised distro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) not for the faint at heart!*

Comment: Part of it was looking Linux up in the Microsoft Store once I found out they now list Linux distros and you can download them.  Other resources were the Complete Privacy and Security Desk Reference by Michael Bazzell and Justin Carroll, which also had resources.

Comment: Part of what I learned has been the result of both programming learning websites like Team Treehouse and Pluralsight and, I say a bit guiltily, paying obsessive attention to the details while watching Mr. Robot...

Comment: So I need to delete the Kali distro I downloaded from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: Well... As you're asking: *Forget about Kali!  Come back to Kali in a few months/years when you've got much more experience...*  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Got it.  I'll just let it sit until then.

Comment: I'd advise against multi-boot setups until you really know what you're doing. There's too much stuff you need to jerry-rig in order to keep it running somewhat stable.

Comment: I've been running dual-boot from day 1, then wiped Windows and running multi-boot since I bought my new machine more than a year ago now.  Once you get the hang of rEFInd and grub, you can do things you cannot do in a VM setup and as OP is interested in Kali: that can't do anything useful in a VM...